# Leaving traling / off messes up loading

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I leave the trailing / off of my URL, it messes up my jquery loading -- the page reloads itself in the comments section.  For example:

http://www.songmeanings.net/songs/view/3530822107858857748

For what it should look like, put the trailing / at the end such as:

http://www.songmeanings.net/songs/view/3530822107858857748/

The root of the problem is how ajax is posting.  My url has to be "./"  -- if I make it "" the inline loading no longer happens, but the comments fail to load then in IE.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "./", data: "........",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current url. Check if that has a trailing slash. If not, add one. Make ajax request to that url.

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (/\/$/.test(url) == false) {
   url = url + "/";
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", url: url, data: "........",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
    ...
```

This ought to solve your problem :)

Comment: weird that this issue is only here and not other pages where I have jquery